# How to use Spacy with Pyinstaller?

Tags: pyinstaller, spacy-3

is there the possibility, that someone could post a working pyinstaller example of a **minnimal** program that includes spacy and a language model?

I tried to follow the tips on stackoverflow, but maybe i dont understand them well. I still get the same error, that the model isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use PyInstaller to package my 'prediction server' using Spacy 2.x, but it took a whale of trials to get all the 'hooks' right.
My prediction server loads the NR model and listens (on a socket) for prediction requests (data). For each request, it returns predicted NR entities.

I got my server working without using GPU. Adding GPU support resulted in a monster executable, which was always missing something - not to mention it would likely be only portable to machine(s) with the same CUDA version.

My SpacyServer.spec:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['SpacyServer.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Work\\ML\\Spacy\\deploy'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=['.'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['cupy'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='SpacyServer',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

And my hook-spacy.py:

```
# HOOK FILE FOR SPACY
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# ----------------------------- SPACY -----------------------------
print('=================== SPACY =====================')
data = collect_all('spacy')

datas = data[0]
binaries = data[1]
hiddenimports = data[2]

# ----------------------------- THINC -----------------------------
data = collect_all('thinc')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- CYMEM -----------------------------
data = collect_all('cymem')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

print(data[2])

# ----------------------------- PRESHED -----------------------------
data = collect_all('preshed')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- BLIS -----------------------------

data = collect_all('blis')

datas += data[0]
binaries += data[1]
hiddenimports += data[2]

# ----------------------------- OTHER ----------------------------

hiddenimports += ['srsly.msgpack.util']

# This hook file is a bit of a hack - really, all of the libraries should be in seperate hook files. (Eg hook-blis.py with the blis part of the hook)
# But it looks we need to process everything when we import spacy, else we do not even hit import cymem.

print('=================== SPACY DONE =====================')
```

Finally, I run:

```
pyinstaller   --onefile   --name SpacyServer SpacyServer.py  --additional-hooks-dir=. --exclude-module=cupy
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i still get the error that the langugage modul isnt found. i installed spacy 2.x like you did and copied the hook file. i used python3.8. my error shows: File "spacy/util.py", line 175, in load_model
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
[14386] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!